# Ruby hash.key error

Tags: ruby, hash

I feel like I'm overlooking something here.  When I try to use the Hash.key(keytolookfor) method, I get an error.

Is this method deprecated?

```
pete@Vader:~/tmp$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
pete@Vader:~/tmp$ ./hashtest.rb
./hashtest.rb:8: undefined method `key' for {"firstkey"=>"firstvalue", "secondkey"=>"secondvalue"}:Hash (NoMethodError)
pete@Vader:~/tmp$
```

The script is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

testHash = Hash.new
testHash["firstkey"] = "firstvalue"
testHash["secondkey"] = "secondvalue"

if testHash.has_value?("secondvalue")
    keyvalue = testHash.key("secondvalue")
    puts "match found with key #{keyvalue}"
else
    puts "no match found"
end
```

Comment: That is valid method..[`Hash#key`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-key) You shouldn't get any error.

Comment: Is it possible that `which ruby` is different from `/usr/bin/ruby` (e.g. using `rvm`)?

Comment: @VictorMoroz, could be, as `ruby 1.8.7` didn't have the `Hash#key` method.

Comment: has my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 2):

My wild guess is that your system ruby `/usr/bin/ruby` is 1.8.7 which doesn't have `Hash#key` method. `ruby -v` most probably shows `rvm` version which is located in `~/.rvm/...`, but first line in your script calls `/usr/bin/ruby`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the heap record for script as follows:

```
#/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This picks up the default ruby version specified by the system, `rvm`, or `rbenv`. Since Ruby 1.8.7 has no [`Hash#key`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-key), make sure that you're running at least Ruby 1.9.1:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -v
1.9.1p0
```

Alternatively, use [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) instead:

```
keyvalue = testHash["secondvalue"]
```